# Rails link_to text field value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, input

I'm using the acts-as-taggable-on gem on my Rails application and would like the users to be able to search for tags rather than just click a list of tag links. The tagged elements are routed to `tags/(tag value)` which is the show view for the tags controller. How would I go about submitting the value of a text field as a url for that tag. For example if I type 'notifications' into the text field and click either a link or a button I would like to render `http://tags/notifications` in the browser.

My routes.rb is as follows:

```
IconLibrary::Application.routes.draw do
  get "icons/admin"
  get "tags/:tag", to: 'tags#show', as: :tag
  get "sign_up" => "user#new", :as => "sign_up"
  resources :icons, :users, :tags
root to: 'icons#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you need to add some javascript to fulfill your purpose.

Here is a solution with a button. when user click on the button, it will redirect the user to what he want.

html file

```
<text id='tag_value'></text>
<button id='btn'>
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    window.location = '/tags/' + $('#tag_value').val()
  })
})
```

for enter key fire on the textfield.

```
$(function(){
  $("#tag_value").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      window.location = '/tags/' + $('#tag_value').val()
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to do. Would be interesting to see how this could be done in Ruby but javascript handles it quite nicely. Thank you so much for you help! As a side note, is there a way to apply this same behavior if the user simply hits enter while focused on the text field?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again! I know that last bit of jQuery will definitely be useful in the future as well.